# Find the domains on which google gadget is installed

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget

I have a developed a Google gadget which has been running for two years. However it uses `OAuth 1.0`. Now I am trying to upgrade it to `OAuth 2.0` by following this:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2

For this purpose I need to know the domains on which my gadget is installed. But from the admin console I do not see the domains on which my gadget is being used, only that 35 users are there.

How do I find out the domains on which my gadget has been installed?

Thanks